Are curves $z^2 - 1 =e^{it}$ and $z= e^{it}$ homeomorphic?
Consider the subspace topology of the plane curves $C_1: z^2 - 1 =e^{it}$  and  $S: z= e^{it}$, $0\leq t < 2\pi$. (as subspace of $\mathbb C$). Are they homeomorphic?
I tried to show that they are homeomorphic by showing $z \mapsto z^2 -1$ is a homeomorphism on $\mathbb C$, i.e. continuous map with continuous inverse and restrict it to the subspace topologies of these two curves.  But $ z \mapsto z^2 -1$ is not a homeomorphism simply because it has no inverse if we do not restrict its argument to $0 \leq \arg z < \pi$.
I also plot $z^2 - 1 = e^{it}$, but I still don't know the answer.

The curves are not homeomorphic. You can remove two points from $C$ in such a way that it is still connected, but you can't do that with the circle.
